# Ruby on rails big decimal value format not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Big Decimal not showing value in numbers

```
a = BigDecimal.new("100.55")
a = * a * a
puts "big decimal #{a}"
```

output

```
big decimal [#<BigDecimal:ad5a6e8,'0.101103025E5',18(45)>]
```

How i can display it in proper format just like 12345.236

Comment: Because youre making an array instead of a. Remove de first *

Comment: First you need to convert value of a to BigDecimal. After that using to_f you can convert it to float value.

e.g. a.first.to_f

Comment: @Fahad You can mark my answer as accepted if it is works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_s('F')` method to convert it to float.

```
a = BigDecimal.new("100.55")
a = a * a
puts "big decimal #{a.to_s('F')}"
=> big decimal 10110.3025
```

Thanks @stefan for suggesting to use `to_s('F')` method instead of `to_f`.

Comment: Note that `Float#to_s` might return a string representation in e-notation, e.g. `0.00001.to_s` returns `"1.0e-05"`. If you want a decimal representation, you should use `a.to_s('F')` instead.